# The Security to the Party [Part 18]

Tags: password

Blah, bah, blah, party, blah, blah, blah, spaghetti.

First guest arrives, guard says "3", guest says "0", and is admitted. 
Second guest arrives, guard says "4", guest says "1", and is admitted. 
Third guest arrives, guard says "8", guest says "2", and is admitted.
Fourth guest arrives, guard says "9", guest says "3", and is admitted.
Fifth guest arrives, guard says "10", guest says "4", and guard says "Umm, I don't know, come back later."
Sixth guest arrives, guard says "11", guest says "5" and is dissolved by acid.
Seventh guest arrive, guard says "18"....   what should the guest answer?

Here's the series: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/party-security

Hint:

> I may need to edit the question later

I won't accept an answer without an explanation of why it is right.

Comment: I wanted to do this one for a while, but wanted to wait until all previous ones were solved. ^^ Nice catch on the solution though! :)

Comment: I was patting myself on the back for just the right amount of false pattern and hinting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My reasoning

> The response is the accepted response to the given party security puzzle - #3 had the answer 0, #4 is currently unknown.

My answer

> We seem to be asked for the answer to this very challenge, which presumably means I can pick any number. I'll go with [12](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aaron_Rodgers).

Comment: Well done!     I thought I was being pretty clever!

Comment: But 42 would have been so much better.

Answer (score 0):

The Guest should answer 6 as the pattern is along the lines of modulus 3 so:
0 % 3 = 0
4 % 3 = 1
8 % 3 = 2
9 % 3 = 3

The Fifth person should have answered 1 to be admitted

Comment: Modulo gives the remainder of the division, thus 9 % 3 is 0, not 3.